# Yii2 create a form without a model

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks, yii2, mailchimp

I was wondering how can I create a form without a model in Yii2 framework as I am creating a mailchimp signup form so a model isn't necessary the below code generates a form however as you can see it uses a model.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Do I still use activeform, how can I remove the $model variable without it throwing up an error?

Comment: Don't know YII, but You can always use plain ol' html....

Comment: @DamienPirsy yeah I was just wondering if it's possible which I am guessing it is however as you say normal html will do the job.

Comment: @DamienPirsy That's the way to go, but YII2 is horrible when it comes to forms, it's nearly impossible to get a form's input into a model. Good reason NOT to use a framework!

Answer (score 11):

Yii2 has this nice little thingy called a [`DynamicModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel.html). 
This basically allows you to create a model on the fly so that you can still use all the `ActiveForm` and validation goodies, but without having to commit to writing an entire model class for it. Might be interesting.

Example from the documentation:

```
public function actionSearch($name, $email)
{
   $model = DynamicModel::validateData(compact('name', 'email'), [
       [['name', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
       ['email', 'email'],
   ]);
   if ($model->hasErrors()) {
      // validation fails
   } else {
      // validation succeeds
   }
}
```

Obviously these instance can also be used for the `ActiveForm`-widget.
You can then run proper validation in your actions first and then pass on your data to MailChimp. Might be handy if you want to run [`HTML Purifier`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-htmlpurifier.html) as part of that validation for the content

Comment: Nice article on DynamicModel at http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/759/create-form-with-dynamicmodel/

Answer (score 5):

use Html Input 
with active form
`<?=Html::input('text','','',['class'=>'form-control'])?>`

Comment: Please complete your answer. Are you suggesting using the html helper to build the mailchimp subscription form?

Comment: @MEM he has provided the correct answer IMHO. What else would he provide? That's the exact widget you need.

Answer (score 0):

As @DamienPirsy suggested - use plain. If you want use yii2 features for it - use Class yii\helpers\BaseHtml (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html) There are all methods to build any form as you want. Then you can operate it in any action in any controller of your application. But this is not true MVC way. That's why Yii/Yii2 advises you to use models.

Comment: Thanks for the advice/info. So are you advising me to use a model even when sending the post data straight from the app to mailchimp list?