# yii2 create a button without any model field

Tags: php, button, yii2, yii2-basic-app, active-form

I need to have two buttons on my home page, Login and Register. When user click on Login button I need to render a LoginView, while on Register button there will be RegisterView. 
I see these questions but these also have fields in model(dynamic model):

[ActiveForm without model yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368084/activeform-without-model-yii2)

[Yii2 create a form without a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331492/yii2-create-a-form-without-a-model/30389428)

I don't want to use any model field, I only want to render different view on click event to different buttons. 
Or in other words, how can I set a button to call specific controller's action on its click event?

How this can be done with Yii2 framework.

Comment: Use `<?= Html::a('label', ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>`

Comment: what about @ZeiZ answer in the second link you provided ? I think related docs could be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#creating-forms).

Comment: Thanks @InsaneSkull, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani, yes that's also another option, but I think Insane's answer is simpler one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<?= Html::a('label', ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```